# Triangular matrix object

Tags: c++, matrix

In a C++ simulation I have an n*n matrix, it's so large that it can't fit my memory, but this matrix is symmetrical, How could I generate only one of the triangular parts and free the other triangle from being held by the memory, this should clear half of the memory.
I use basic vector or Eigen Library

Comment: Store all the data in a linear array where you play with the indices. Means that for each `i, j` you end up with a `k` that represents both array[i][j] and array[j][i] since its symmetrical so they both will be same. Now how to choose that `k` from `i & j` is maths

Comment: For example if I'm taking left bottom triangle and storing it in 1D array then [0][0] should be at [0], (1,0) at 1, (1,1) at 2, (2,0) at 3, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a vector of different sized vectors, like this:

```
int main() {
 const int size = 10;
 vector<vector<int>> matrix;

 for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
  // Each vector is of size i 
  matrix.push_back(vector<int>(i));
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Just wrap this in a 'symmetrical matrix' class and add appropriate accessor methods.

You could do something similar with raw arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this suit your purposes?  This only uses memory for the "upper triangular" matrix, but has an interface that can access any of the n-by-n elements (under the assumption of symmetry):

```
class Symmetric {
public:
    Symmetric(int n);
    int& AccessElement(int row, int col);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > data;
};

Symmetric::Symmetric(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::vector<int> row(n - i);
        data.push_back(row);
    }
}

int& Symmetric::AccessElement(int row, int col) {
    int r = row;
    int c = col;
    if (col < row) {
        r = col;
        c = row;
    } 
    return data[r][c - r];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this cleanly with a class that uses a single dimensional vector to store the data. you then need an accessor function that translates your row and col input into its single dimensional equivalent.

```
class TriangularMatrix {
private:
    int m_size;
    std::vector<int> m_data;
public:
    int& Get(int row, int col);
    TriangularMatrix(int size);
};
```

now there are two questions left:

- how do you initialize the size?
- what is the accessor function

Notice, the size will be

```
n + n-1 + n-2 +...1 = n *(n-1)/2
```

which is common formula for summation of 1 to n. Therefore your constructor looks like this:

```
TriangularMatrix::TriangularMatrix(int size): m_size(size), m_data(size*(size - 1)/2){}
```

for the accessor, notice that the sum of row and column should never be greater than *n* -1, as if it is you have crossed the diagonal. Therefore it ought to swap row and col if it their sum is greater than *n* - 1. Next, notice the pattern:

```
(0, i) -> i                             = 0n + i  
(1, i) -> n + i                         = 1n + i  
(2, i) -> n + n - 1 + i                 = 2n - 1 + i  
(3, i) -> n + n - 1 + n - 2 + i         = 3n - 3 + i  
(4, i) -> n + n - 1 + n - 2 + n - 3 + i = 4n - 6 + i  
...
```

and in general,

```
(row,col) -> row*n +(row-1)*(row-2)/2 + col
```

as the constant term will be the sum from 1 to row - 1.

Therefore your accessor will look like this:

```
int& TriangularMatrix::Get(int row, int col){
    if(row + col >= m_size){
        return m_data[col * m_size + (col -1)*(col-2)/2 + row]
    }
    return m_data[row * m_size + (row -1)*(row-2)/2 + col]          
}
```